# PostgreSQL pg_restore errors: GRANT, REVOKE

Tags: database, postgresql, restore

I attempted to restore a PostgreSQL 9.5 database using this command:

```
pg_restore -C -d postgres -U postgres --no-owner --role=jsmith the_data.dump
```

Because the cluster I restored to is not the same as the cluster the dump was made on, some of the roles don't exist.

There were many errors during the restore, but all of them involved `GRANT` and `RESTORE`.  Can I assume the actual data itself was restored without loss or modification?

Comment: Those messages are typically WARNINGs not errors. And yes, you can ignore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GRANT` and `REVOKE` errors can be ignored.  They don't effect the data load.

If you want to avoid the messages in future you can use the `-x` parameter on `pg_restore`  (you can also use the synonyms `--no-acl` or `--no-privileges`
).

This stops `pg_restore` trying to set the grants.

pg_restore docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: Thanks.  I did see the `--no-privileges` option in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271402/pg-restore-error-role-xxx-does-not-exist#comment72931604_37271854), though only after I ran the restore command.